# Maven command line interface

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

Is there any option/plugin for maven command line interface that allow us to create a new project ? I mean for something user friendly like npm is.

Something like typing on a console `$ xptocli init` ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got so frustrated with the very long maven command that you have to write that I wrote a bash script for this exact purpose. I call it `mvnproj` and saved it in `usr/local/bin`. Here is the code

```
if [ $# -eq 4 ]; then
  cd $1
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=$4.$3.$2 -DartifactId=$2 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false;
elif [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=$3.$2.$1 -DartifactId=$1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false;
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=$2.$1 -DartifactId=$1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false;
else
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=$1 -DartifactId=$1 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false;
fi
```

You can call it in 4 different ways

1. `mvnproj dir projname groupname tld`
2. `mvnproj projname groupname tld`
3. `mvnproj projname groupname`
4. `mvnproj projname`

For 1. `dir` is the directory where you want it placed, in 2-4, it will be placed in the directory you are currently in. `projname` is the name of your project, `groupname` is your company's name, and `tld` is the top level domain of your company. Example calls

1. `mvnproj /tmp example stackoverflow com`
2. `mvnproj example stackoverflow com`
3. `mvnproj example stackoverflow`
4. `mvnproj example`

Comment: wow that is definitely not user friendly! but nice work!

Comment: I added a description of how to use it. It actually makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven's Archetype Plugin to create a new project:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -B \
  -DgroupId=org.mygroup \
  -DartifactId=myartifact \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/)

In order to create the simplest of Maven projects, execute the following from the command line:

**Note:** The Archetype Plugin (`mvn archetype:generate`) allows the user to create a Maven project, this plugin is included with maven by default.

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
```

Once you have executed this command, you will notice that a **directory named my-app** has been created under **C:\Users\yourname\my-app** (in windows 7) and this directory contains a file named **pom.xml** that should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```